# Can I modify the bytes which are requested to read but not read in reality of InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream

In official JDK docs, the `java.io.InputStream#read(byte[], int, int)` said:

> Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes will be stored in elements b[off] through b[off+k-1], leaving elements b[off+k] through b[off+len-1] unaffected.

But after the sentence, the next paragraph said:

> In every case, elements b[0] through b[off-1] and elements b[off+len] through b[b.length-1] are unaffected.

The first sentence requires a more strong limitation of the read operation.

I'm writing an implementation that extends from the InputStream.
The documentation said, "unaffected". I interpret it as it can't be modified during the read operation. But even for the b[off+k]~b[off+len-1] also is **not able** to be modified?
I want to use the whole buffer [off, off+len) to processing data temporary.

Comment: First seems to say that only bytes after are left unaffected, second seems to say that bytes after _and before_ are left unaffected. The second sentence seems to be a superset of the first. What do you mean with "touch"? You shouldn't be touching private members of other classes.

Comment: The first quoted sentence is describing (focusing on) what happens with read bytes; second sentence is describing what happens with bytes not being affected - both are **part** of the specification; neither one "*is enough*", and even both together are not "*enough*"; actually, what do you mean by "*is enough*"? Enough for what? -- well, considering the title "*the bytes which are requested to read*", the second quoted sentence does not add any relevant information, assuming that `b[0]` through `b[off-1]` are not being requested -- *maybe* an example would actually be helpful :-/

Comment: @knittl  I update my question describe what I want, thank you.

Comment: That's right, `b[off+k]` to `b[off+len-1]` will not be modified. If you thought they _could_ be modified, what do you think they might be set to?

Comment: @user85421 Yes, my question is only focus on the segment that specified in the first paragraph. The part that requested to read but not fulfilled with valid data. My question is what the meaning of "unaffected"? Can I modify it with mess data?

Comment: "unaffected", as I understand, means that the method will not change these bytes, that is, you can modify these "unaffected" data (before the call and it will not be changed after the call returns; for example it will not be filled with zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning `InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`, the following scenarios are possible:

1. There are `len` or more bytes available in the stream. In this case, the bytes `b[off]` to `b[off + len - 1]` will be written. All other bytes in the buffer `b` will not be modified.
2. There are less than `len` bytes in the stream. Let k be the total number of bytes that can be read. In this case, the bytes `b[off]` to `b[off + k - 1]` will be written. All other bytes in the buffer `b` will not be modified.

In particular, your InputStream implementation is **not** allowed to first clear the contents of `b` from `off` to `off + len - 1` before attempting to read the stream.

There are other possible scenarios: those involving exceptions. These scenarios are out of scope of this question.

Comment:  That means I need an additional buffer to process data temporary.

Comment: @iseki why? You just don't need to clear those bytes before reading them. If you only read `k` instead of `len` bytes, you will only _write_ `k` instead of `len` bytes. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm writing a strings. I want to implement the resd(byte[],int,int) to improve performance and avoid too many read call. That means before I read the whole buffer I don't know the k.

Comment: You can improve performance by using `BufferedInputStream`. In any case, you don't need to know `k`, you just need to attempt to write up to `len` bytes into `b`, and if you only manage to read `k` bytes from the stream instead, then you only write `k` bytes into `b`.

Comment: I just want to reduce the read call. Even it might be optimized by JIT.

Answer (score 1):

The buffer `b` is conceptually split into for parts:

- from `0` to `off-1`: these bytes are unaffected (2. paragraph)
- from `off` to `off+k-1`: these contain the bytes that have been read (1. paragraph)
- from `off+k` to `off+len-1`: this range was included in the read request but has not been changed because of insufficient data (1. paragraph)
- from `off+len` to `off+b.length-1`: these bytes are unaffected (2. paragraph)

There is no overlap between those four ranges.

Comment: Yes, it's my wrong. The two paragraph describe 2 part of the buffer. I read it wrong. I update my question describe what I want, thank you.